# Bind command to `DataTemplate` in `ContextMenu` when using multiple templates?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I'm trying to give a context menu items with different look and functionality, but I cannot find a way to bind commands to these items. Each menu item's view model is derived from one class `AbstractEntryViewModel`. Here is a shortened example of my current project's structure. Using `ContextMenu.Resources` is the only way I found to bind a template to a certain type.

```xml
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NopEntryViewModel}">
            <!-- Content -->
        </DataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            DataType="{x:Type local:GroupEntryViewModel}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
            <!-- Content -->
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <!-- More templates -->

    </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```

```cs
internal abstract AbstractEntryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public abstract void Invoke ();
    // ...
}

internal NopEntryViewModel : AbstractEntryViewModel {
    public override void Invoke () {}
}

internal GroupEntryViewModel : AbstractEntryViewModel {
    public override void Invoke () { /* ... */ }
    // ...
}

// More view models
```

Normally I can bind a command to a `MenuItem` like so

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding StaticResourceOrViewModelProperty}" />
```

**How can I do the same thing with data templates? Is there an invisible container, a wrapper for the data template's content, that I can use to bind a command to?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, suppose 2 derived ViewModels, `VM1` and `VM2`, with respectively a `Command` `Command1` and a `Command2`.

Two steps:

1) Define in the base `ViewModel` this property:

```
public Type Type
{
    get { return GetType(); }
}
```

We cannot use `GetType()` directly, we need a wrapping property since WPF `Bindings` work only with properties.

2) Use this property to set a `DataTrigger` on the `Style` for the `ContextMenu` `MenuItem`:

```
<ContextMenu.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Type local:VM1}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command1}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="{x:Type local:VM2}">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command2}"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <!-- add other DataTriggers, one for every ViewModel --> 
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</ContextMenu.Resources>
```

The `DataTemplates` are set as you do, with:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
  <!-- Content -->
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
  <!-- Content -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: WOW, works like a charm and doesn't break MVVM :) When using an additional setter `<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />`, the actual view model instance is passed into the command. Thank you very much :)